# Is the sharp dollar (#$) sign the same as load-file-name in Emacs?

Tags: syntax

I see Emacs use `#$` in autoload files, but I don't known if there are any difference between `#$` and `load-file-name`. When I use them in a file, they looks like the same and when I print them by `M-:` they are both `nil`. So I did some test but only get more confused. Does `#$` behave more like `__FILE__` in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask Emacs.

`M-x elisp-index-search RET #$ RET`

> Internally, the dynamic loading of documentation strings is
>   accomplished by writing compiled files with a special Lisp reader
>   construct, ‘#@COUNT’.  This construct skips the next COUNT characters.
>   It also uses the ‘#$’ construct, which stands for “the name of this
>   file, as a string”.  Do not use these constructs in Lisp source files;
>   they are not designed to be clear to humans reading the file.

Comment: Note that you can do that kind of search when inside an info document by using `C-s`, entering the term and hitting `C-s` repeatedly.